# Having trouble passing a variable in Jquery function

Tags: jquery

I have this function

```
function procData(a) {
    $('#loading' + a).show();
    $.post("ajax.php?talk=" + a, {
        slot: $('#slot' + a).val()
    }, function (response) {
        $('#talkdesc' + a).fadeOut();
        setTimeout("finishAjax('talkdesc', a, '" + escape(response) + "')", 400);
    });
}

function finishAjax(id, a, response) {
    $('#' + id + a).html(unescape(response));
    $('#' + id + a).fadeIn();
}
```

In procData(), I'm trying to pass the variable 'a' to finishAjax, but nothing seems to work.  It works in all the areas where it is called except this one.  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

```
setTimeout(function () {
    finishAjax('talkdesc', a, escape(response));
}, 400);
```

Comment: The horror! Don't pass strings to `setTimeout`. I'm going to modify your answer to use an anonymous function.